# drush migrate:upgrade not behaving as expected

Tags: 8, migrations

I'm working with [the Migrate Tools modules](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_tools) for the first time. Specifically, I'm trying to use [the Migrate Upgrade module](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_upgrade) to import users and roles from an old Drupal 7 site to a new, Drupal 8 rebuild of that site.

Per [these instructions](https://www.drupal.org/docs/upgrading-drupal/upgrade-using-drush#s-generating-migrations-using-migrate-upgrade), I'm running this command to configure the migrations:

```
drush migrate:upgrade --legacy-db-url=mysql://olduser:password@localhost/oldschema --legacy-root=http://olddomain.test:8888 --configure-only
```

When I run `drush migrate:status upgrade_d7_user,upgrade_d7_user_role` immediately after that command, here's what I see:

```
----------------------------------------- ---------------------- -------- ------- ---------- ------------- --------------- 
 Group                                     Migration ID           Status   Total   Imported   Unprocessed   Last Imported  
----------------------------------------- ---------------------- -------- ------- ---------- ------------- --------------- 
 Import from Drupal 7 (migrate_drupal_7)   upgrade_d7_user_role   Idle     4       4          0                            
 Import from Drupal 7 (migrate_drupal_7)   upgrade_d7_user        Idle     197     196        0                            
----------------------------------------- ---------------------- -------- ------- ---------- ------------- ---------------
```

This isn't what I expect to see. It looks like it has *already* imported all roles and all users (except for the admin user), and has none left to process. I expect to see *zero* imported at this point, since I used the `--configure-only` flag, and I haven't yet issued the Drush command to actually *run* the migrations.

Looking in the Drupal backend, I don't see that anything has actually been imported.

If I go ahead and run these commands:

```
drush migrate:import upgrade_d7_user_role
drush migrate:import upgrade_d7_user
```

...then I see:

```
[notice] Processed 0 items (0 created, 0 updated, 0 failed, 0 ignored) - done with 'upgrade_d7_user_role'
[notice] Processed 0 items (0 created, 0 updated, 0 failed, 0 ignored) - done with 'upgrade_d7_user'
```

It seems like the Migrate Tools *thinks* that the imports have already been completed – but they haven't.

Any ideas? Has anyone run into anything similar before?

I *have* been restoring the new (target) site's database from a snapshot periodically, because I'm learning the migration process as I go. So maybe that has hosed something up.

The very first time I ran `migrate:status`, I saw what I expected – some records queued, but none imported yet.

And the first time I ran `migrate:import`, it did import the records as expected.

So it seems like something about that previous import got "stuck" somewhere in the system. But I've taken increasingly drastic measures to burn my development site to the ground and rebuild from scratch – to no avail.

Is there perhaps something being cached by the Drush CLI itself?

Appreciate any suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out!

I just needed to run `drush migrate:rollback`. That put Drupal back into a state where it understood that the migrations hadn't actually been run yet.